# Linear system of divisors on complete variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

I am currently reading Mumford's abelian varieties and Milne's notes on them and I have a problem understanding the proof that they are projective. Both of them use that a complete linear system of divisors on the abelian variety $V$ defines a morphism $V\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$ ($k$ can be assumed algebraically closed). The problem I have with this is that they seem to assume that the $k$-vector space
$$
L(D)\cup \{0\}=\{f\in k(V)^{\times}|~div(f)+D\geq 0\}\cup \{0\}
$$
is finite dimensional. Can anybody help me with this?

This is true for projective schemes $X$ by theorem 5.19 in Hartshorne that says that $\Gamma(X,F)$ is finite-dimensional for any coherent sheaf $F$ and our vector space is $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}(D))$. However we don't know that $V$ is projective yet. I think the crucial property of $V$ we need to use here is completeness.

I'll include definition and some basic properties: An abelian variety is per definition a complete connected group variety. They are non-singular, geometrically irreducible and commutative.

Comment: Shafarevich calls this the "Finiteness Theorem" and proves it for complete varieties over a field (see IV.3.4 Theorem).

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks!

Comment: Over a field, the finiteness theorem was first proved by Serre in his celebrate paper "Faisceaux algébriques cohérents", Ann. Math. in 1955. The general case with higher cohomology groups coherent sheaves over proper schemes is called theorem of direct image and is proved by Grothendieck.

Comment: @QiL: Thanks, I found that Milne actually mentions that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a little bit of an overkill, but anyway.

It seems that more generally, if $f: X \rightarrow S$ is proper, where $S=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, with $A$ a noetherian ring, then for every coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ the cohomology groups

$$
H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})
$$

are $A$-modules of finite type, for every $i \in \Bbb{N}$. [Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9202012v1.pdf) is an arxiv-reference; the author attributes the aforementioned result to Grothendieck.

What you are asking about is the particular case $i=0$, $X=V$ an abelian variety, $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}(D)$; then $$\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}(D)) \cong H^0(V,\mathcal{O}(D))$$

is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space.

Comment: A reference for this is lemma 25.17.4 of the Stacks project: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O6

Comment: Actually now I found that Milne mentions this (slightly more general): THEOREM 4.1. If $f: V \rightarrow T is a proper regular map and $F$ is a coherent $O_V$-module,
then the higher direct image sheaves $R^r(f_{*}F)$ are coherent $O_T$ -modules for all $r\geq 0$.

Comment: Lol, I forgot to close an equation and now I can't edit or delete the comment because it goes into the "Related" column...