# Coherent sheaves with full support

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is about a particular step in the proof of the Finiteness theorem (I asked about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296235/linear-system-of-divisors-on-complete-variety#comment645086_296235)) by Shafarevic (Theorem 2.3.5). I started summing up the whole proof but it is probably easier if I just ask about this particular step: Suppose we have a coherent sheaf $F$ on a complete variety $X$ such that its support is $X$. Shafarevic then says that there exists an open set $U$ such that $O_X^m|_U\cong F|_U$. Could somebody explain that to me, or is it wrong?

Comment: I don't think, completeness is necessary. Look at Shafarevich's "Basic algebraic geometry 2" (second, revised and expanded version) page 90, D\'evissage of coherent sheaves, which is; For a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over a Noetherian reduced irreducible scheme $X,$ there exists a (dense) open subset $W \subset X$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}|_W$ is free.

Comment: Dear @ehsanmo: please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Oh that's helpful... I had the first edition of the book and the proof there is probably slightly wrong, since it was replaced by a proof that's twice as long. @ehsanmo: Indeed you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Shafarevich's "Basic algebraic geometry 2" (second, revised and expanded version) page 90, D\'evissage of coherent sheaves, which is; For a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over a Noetherian reduced irreducible scheme $X,$ there exists a (dense) open subset $W \subset X$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}|_W$ is free.

Comment: In fact, this is true in more generality: Any $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite type on a reduced scheme $X$ (not necessarily Noetherian or irreducible) is free on some dense open subset. (Compare Ravi Vakil's notes, exercise 13.7.K. By using the topos-theoretic internal language, this immediately follows from the following fact of constructive linear algebra: Any finitely generated vector space is *not not* free.)